# Adding provider to providers array does not work

Tags: angular, angular-providers

I want to add a provider to my providers array based on some condition. Adding this way does not work

```
const tempProviders: Array<any> = [
  abcService,
  xyzService];

if(IE) {
tempProviders.push({provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS,
    useClass: IeInputEventManagerService,
    deps: [DOCUMENT],
    multi: true
});
}

@NgModule -> continues here
```

Above does not work. What is the right way of pushing the new provider to provider array.

Answer (score 0):

create a function and assign the new object against the array.

```
const tempProviders: Array<any> = [
  abcService,
  xyzService,
  checkService(),
];


function checkService(){
 if(IE) {
  return {provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS,
    useClass: IeInputEventManagerService,
    deps: [DOCUMENT],
    multi: true,
  };
 }
}
```

Comment: I get AOT error Function calls are not supported in decorators.

Comment: try `export function checkService(){`